# Find and remove overlapping polygons with GeoPandas

Tags: python, geopandas, intersection, overlay

I have 2 data frames, let's say, `df1` and `df2`. I need to find `df1` polygons that overlay with `df2` (the green line), and remove them from main dataframe `df1`.

I do not need to extract a overlaying part or create a new dataframe, I need to identify the ones which overlays in any cases and remove them. The result would be `df1` with the removed polygons.

I tried to use GeoPandas intersect and overlay, however, could not find the solution. Both dataframes have the same coordinate system.

```
import pandas as pd
import geopandas as gpd

df1 = gpd.read_file(r'E:\...\dfs1.shp')
df2 = gpd.read_file(r'E:\...\dfs2.shp')

print(df1.crs, df1.crs)

res_intersection = gpd.overlay(df1, df2, how='intersection')
```

> TypeError: `keep_geom_type` does not support None.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried explicitly setting `keep_geom_type` to `True`? In the docs, it says the default value of `None` should set the argument to `True` but this doesn't seem to be happening for you. https://geopandas.org/en/stable/docs/reference/api/geopandas.overlay.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [spatial join](https://geopandas.org/en/stable/gallery/spatial_joins.html):

```
import geopandas as gpd
    
df1 = gpd.read_file(r'/home/bera/Desktop/gistemp/greens.shp')
df2 = gpd.read_file(r'/home/bera/Desktop/gistemp/buildings.shp')
df2['savedindex']= df2.index #Save the index values as a new column

intersecting = df1.sjoin(df2, how='inner')['savedindex'] #Find the polygons that intersect. Keep savedindex as a series

df2 = df2[~df2.savedindex.isin(intersecting)] #Filter away these, "savedindex is not in intersecting"

df2.to_file(r'/home/bera/Desktop/gistemp/buildings_disjoint.shp')
```

[image]

Comment: For potential user: As I work with large datasets, execution time is important. And this definitely work much faster than the solution of new_df1 = df1.loc[df1.intersects(df2.unary_union)].reset_index(drop=True). Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following:

```py
new_df1 = df1.loc[~df1.intersects(df2.unary_union)].reset_index(drop=True)
```

The `new_df1` GeoDataFrame will contain all the observations/rows/features from `df1` that **DO NOT** intersect with the elements of `df2`.

Comment: Just to know, how it would be to get features from df1 that DO intersect with the elements of df2. Is it the same line, just a little modified?

Comment: You're exactly right, the only difference is the tilde (`~`): `new_df1 = df1.loc[df1.intersects(df2.unary_union)].reset_index(drop=True)`. Think of the tilde character as a element-wise NOT operator. `df1.intersects(df2.unary_union)` generates a `pd.Series` of boolean values and the tilde (`~`) operator just inverts them.